# adding a class to form_submit in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a class to form_submit  in PHP Codeigniter; Im doing with the following code:

```
        $attributes1=array(
            'class'=>'btn btn-danger',
        );
        echo form_submit('loginSubmit', 'Login',$attributes1['class']);
```

But the rendered code in HTML is as following:

```
<input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="Login" btn="" btn-danger="">
```

could you please let me know who I can the class to my form_submit?

Also If it is not clear please let me know which part is ambiguous so I will provide more clarification

Many thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use Like this

```
echo form_submit('loginSubmit', 'Login',"class='btn btn-danger'");
```

Comment: Thanks! So I cannot pass it as an array at all?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html Read this guide. If u want to use attribute as array u can write your own helper

Answer (score 3):

I use it like this:

```
echo form_submit(array(
        'id' => 'submit', 
        'value' => 'Enter', 
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
     ));
```