# How to add style or put a class in a php form_submit button

Tags: php, html, css

I just want my button to look awesome but I don't know how to apply styles or to put class on a button like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFvzg.jpg

```
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?>
```

I want to put this css properties to my button to make it look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmFLI.jpg..

```
.btnBack{
      background: #3498db;
      border: solid 1px;
      border-color: #3498db;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
      -webkit-border-radius: 5;
      -moz-border-radius: 5;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 100px;
      text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

please teach me how to do it.. thanks

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236867/adding-a-class-to-form-submit-in-php-codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is code igniter:

```
form_submit('submit', 'Submit',"class='btnBack'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit',"class='btnBack'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the class in your css file, and call it "buttonSubmit" (or whatever you prefer_ and add it like so -

```
<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit','class=buttonSubmit'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is the CodeIgniter form_submit function - per the docs for the form_submit function, https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html, "the third parameter lets you add extra data to your form, like JavaScript.", so you can pass a string with a class as the third parameter (and any other additional attributes you want to add) like this:

```
echo form_submit('submit','Submit','class="btnBack"');
```

You can alternatively pass an array as the first parameter to achieve the same, if you prefer that syntax.

```
echo form_submit(array('name' => 'submit','value' => 'Submit','class' => 'btnBack'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

.btnBack{
      background: #3498db;
      border: solid 1px;
      border-color: #3498db;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
      -webkit-border-radius: 5;
      -moz-border-radius: 5;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 15px;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 100px;
      text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<?php

function form_submit($type, $value, $style){

    echo "<form action='#' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='$type' value='$value' class=$style";
}

form_submit('submit', 'Submit', 'btnBack');

?>

</body>
</html>
```